# Plotly 3D Surface graph does not show all the x and y co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, 3d, plotly

On executing the code given below, all the z co-ordinates are shown correctly but, the x-axis shows only 1-10 co-ordinates and y-axis shows only s1,s2,s3,s4 co-ordinates. How can I plot all the co-ordinates in this 3D surface graph?

```js
var data = [{
  z: [
    [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10],
    [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11],
    [3.5, 4.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 10],
    [5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 12.5, 17]
  ],
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
  y: ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9', 's10'],
  type: 'surface'
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Trips Overview',
  scene: {
    xaxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      titlefont: {
        color: 'red',
        family: 'Arial, Open Sans',
        size: 12
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'stops',
      titlefont: {
        color: 'red',
        family: 'Arial, Open Sans',
        size: 12
      }
    },
    zaxis: {
      title: 'trips',
      titlefont: {
        color: 'red',
        family: 'Arial, Open Sans',
        size: 12
      }
    }
  },
  autosize: true
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked plotly surface plotting in codepen, So for each of the X axis and Y axis values in the arrays, there should be a corresponding sub-array within the z array.

```
E.g:
In your code
X axis: 1
Y axis: "s1"
will have the Z values as [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10].
```

Thus you have provided only 4 lists for Z array, hence we cannot see "s5" above.

Reference:

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, I have unequal no: of x and y co-ordinates and I need to plot them against z axis in a 3d surface graph. Is there any other possible way to do that?

Comment: @AkshayaCB Missing values for Z can be given as [13,14,0,15]  or like [13,14,,15], but the length of the Z sub array must be the same as the arrays of X and Y

Comment: @AkshayaCB did this help you, is this the correct answer to your question?